# Extract Coefficient from Root Formula

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

I have a solution in the form

```
Root[a + b #1 + c #1^2 &, 1]
```

with {a,b,c} very long symbolic expressions
How can I extract the coefficient {a,b,c}?
I'd like to obtain a result like

```
coeff={a,b,c}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your starting point is an explicit number (i.e. it has no symbolic parameters), then you could use [`MinimalPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalPolynomial.html) and [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html).

This works with a [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) object ...

```
MinimalPolynomial[Root[1 + 2 #1 + #1^5 &, 1], x]
(* 1 + 2 x + x^5 *)

CoefficientList[%, x]
(* {1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

... or any other algebraic number.

```
MinimalPolynomial[Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3], x]
(* 1 - 10 x^2 + x^4 *)

CoefficientList[%, x]
(* {1, 0, -10, 0, 1} *)
```

Do keep in mind that MinimalPolynomial will aim to generate a polynomial with integer coefficients.  Thus be aware of results like this:

```
MinimalPolynomial[Root[1 + 2 #1 + Sqrt[2] #1^2 &, 1], x]
(* -1 - 4 x - 4 x^2 + 2 x^4 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is automatically evaluated into the quadratic solution

```
Root[a + b #1 + c #1^2 &, 1]

(*  -(b/(2 c)) - 1/2 Sqrt[(b^2 - 4 a c)/c^2]  *)
```

To maintain the [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) form, the polynomial must be a higher order. For example,

```
expr = Root[a + b #1 + c #1^5 &, 1]

(*  Root[a + b #1 + c #1^5 &, 1]  *)
```

Just use the first argument of `Root` to form a polynomial in x and then use [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html)

```
CoefficientList[expr[[1]][x], x]

(*  {a, b, 0, 0, 0, c}  *)
```